# Dead battery or bad starter

Tags: starter

2013 Mitsubishi Outlander. Newer battery, but car sometimes won’t crank over. Then battery dies. When it gets jumped it usually starts and will start for a week or two then same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Start the car and then while it is started take off the positive cable if it dies it's the alternator it kind of sounds like that could be it but I might be wrong if anything take the starter off and get it tested at a parts store you can also try when you're trying to start it and it wont crank hit the starter with a hammer not too hard tapping a bunch of times and if it starts then you know it's the starter

Comment: In my opinion it's never a good idea to disconnect the battery of a running vehicle. It doesn't prove the alternator is fully functioning.

Comment: Agree with @mikes here ... this is a bad way to do it and can fry not only the alternator (even if it is good), as well as other sensitive electronic parts throughout the car. [See my answer here about the subject.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/38927/4152)